# Swift 4.2, String firstIndex() function error in Xcode playground

Tags: swift, xcode

I was reading "The Swift Programming Language
Swift 4.2" and in "Strings and Characters" chapter under "Substrings" section, the following code is given as an example:

```
let greeting = "Hello, world!"
let index = greeting.firstIndex(of: ",") ?? greeting.endIndex
let beginning = greeting[..<index]
// beginning is "Hello"

// Convert the result to a String for long-term storage.
let newString = String(beginning)
```

I copied and pasted this chunk into my Xcode playground; however, I got the following error:

```
Playground execution failed:

error: MyPlayground.playground:6:13: error: value of type 'String' has 
no member 'firstIndex'
let index = greeting.firstIndex(of: ",") ?? greeting.endIndex
            ^~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~
```

I checked that there is indeed a method called firstIndex() for the String class on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string.

I have **import UIKit;** at the top of my playground.

Can you let me know why I might be getting this error?

Comment: As far as I tested the code you have shown in my Xcode 10 beta 4, it runs as expected. Swift 4.2 comes with Xcode 10. Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @OOPer Apparently, I was using 9.4.1 version of Xcode. I didn't realize that Swift 4.2 comes with Xcode 10 beta 4. My apologies. I will make sure to check next time.

Comment: In fact, Apple is not good at showing version info and many developers are wondering with beta docs shown. Maybe we developers need to send more request to Apple, to improve the developers' site.

Comment: @OOPer  I will definitely let them know that I had this problem and would like them to warn us about the versions in a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `index(of`

```
let index = greeting.index(of: ",") ?? greeting.endIndex
```

as  `firstIndex` exists in Xcode 10 beta [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2997120-firstindex)

Comment: It worked, thank you. However, could you clarify why the given example gives an error although there seems to be a method called firstIndex() ?

Comment: documentation is always updated for the latest  swift version , your link documents Swift's String class not the method firstIndex

Comment: I assumed that it would be updated only for final releases and not betas. However, I learned that is not the case and will check this next time.